# GRUB won't disable or it requires input

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am running ubuntu 12.04 precise:

I am trying to stop the grub menu from displaying but here is the issue, it won't disable.

I have followed this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-in-the-beginning-of-boot

but it does not work and I feel as if I may have the bug that it mentions but I am struggling to get around the bug.

I have set minus options on the timeout. True, false and adding GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true

but I am getting no where. I am truly stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue and from searching the internet many had this issue:

There is a code block in /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

The code block is started by the statement:

```
terminal_output gfxterm #just below this line
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then #this line is the start
```

Delete EVERYTHING within that if block, all sub ifs, everything.

then where the if statment was type (just below the gfxterm line):

```
set timeout=1 #or what ever number you want it to be
```

save file and reboot (do not update grub) and BOOM done.